# MySQL trigger: Update when reaching a certain datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, triggers

I want to create a MySQL trigger that updates a table everytime one of the datetime rows in a different table reaches a datetime lower than now.

**How would I accomplish this? Is that even possible?**

To illustrate:

```
table_1                           table_2      
--------   -------------------    --------   -
id         1                      id         1
datetime   2011-05-10 11:11:11    counter    1
```

So, when time passes and `NOW()` becomes `2011-05-10 11:11:12`, then I want to have the counter upped by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it using a trigger and the event scheduler:
- create a trigger on the table that is fired on every update / insert
- this trigger creates a scheduled event that occurs at the datetime of the row and updates your second table

Answer (score 3):

You could use [MySQL's Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).