# How to combine a trigger and an event and have the event use a specific row id?

Tags: mysql, events, triggers

I have the following problem to solve. I need rows inserted into a "reservations" table to, upon insertion, set a timer for themselves and then check a flag within this newly created row some minutes later to see if it has changed from "pending" to "completed" (which would be caused by user action in the intervening period) and if still "pending" to remove themselves from the table.

The idea here is that people are making reservations and the act of beginning the reservations process adds this row, however, if they fail to complete the purchase over a period of time I want to remove the rows to make the reservations (of which there is a finite amount) available to other consumers.

So, I've been looking at events and triggers and I get the concept for both, but what I'm failing to find is a way for the trigger to pass *this row's id to the event so that when the event fires it only looks at the relevant row because I don't want it to notice *all the rows that might be "pending" since there may have been newly created "pending" rows by other consumers for other reservations in the intervening period, and I obviously don't want to mess with those until their respective timers have elapsed.

So... what I am hoping for (in pseudo) is...

```
/*EVENT*/
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS delete_abandoned_pending_purchase
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5 minutes
DO
  delete from tickets where state = 'PENDING' and id = [MY ROW ID]
```

and then...

```
/*trigger*/
CREATE TRIGGER remove_if_unused
AFTER INSERT ON `tickets` FOR EACH ROW
begin
[call delete_abandoned_pending_purchase with row_id MY_NEW_ROW_ID]
end
```

I'm guessing maybe I need to make a stored procedure that takes a parameter and then pass that row ID as the param? Or perhaps there's a more straight forward way... I'm just failing to find the syntax for this and would love some guidance.  Obviously I can handle this in the business logic that wraps this data interaction, but felt that this was a more elegant approach.

[EDIT]

[reading more about this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)
"There is no way to pass parameters directly to or from events; however, it is possible to invoke a stored routine with parameters within an event".

But the suggestion there is to call a stored procedure and pass it a param.  However, my problem is that I don't see how to get *at the row.id in the event to pass to the stored proc.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious... how can events not have access to specific row ids?

[EDIT EDIT]
so, based [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841030/how-to-create-mysql-event-inside-a-procedure-or-trigger) I'm sensing that this is actually not doable in mySQL... that's a bummer and also quite surprising. Seems like a really obvious thing to want to do.

I'll leave the question open and see if anyone chimes in with a clever alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you do this via a script, less complexity and more control. Something like below:

```
MaxSleep=300 # In seconds SleepTime=MaxSleep
while (1) {   
    sleep SleepTime;   delete from TheTable where reserved = 'pending' and the_timestamp >= Current_Timestamp;   SleepTime='mysql
 'select the_timestamp from TheTable where reserved = 'pending' order
by the_timestamp limit 1"

   if SleepTime is null then SleepTime= MaxSleep 
 }
```

Comment: is there any harm in setting an event to do the exact same thing (via code) every time a new ticket row is added?  I really don't like the notion of having timeouts sitting around in Node (which is what my business logic is in), waiting for multi minute stretches.  Do mySQL Events carry too much overhead?

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct even though I think I prefer the event method, the obvious answer to my actual question is that this is not possible in mySQL at this time... so, your solution is a perfectly plausible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an event that checks against the whole table, should be fast if it is indexed correctly and then the business logic is in the DB. Perhaps use a minute as the check then max pending transaction is 6 Minutes if you have a 5 minute timeout.

CREATE EVENT delete_abandoned_pending_purchase
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 Minutes
    DO
      BEGIN
        delete from TheTable where reserved = 'pending' and the_timestamp >= Current_Timestamp;
      END