# mysql - how to create trigger for payment status

Tags: mysql, triggers, payment

I have two tables, Booking and Payment
Here is the structure :

> **Booking**
>   id_booking (Primary)
>   id_schedule
>   id_user
>   date_booking
>   date_expired
>
> **Payment**
>   id_payment (Primary)
>   id_booking (Foreign Key)
>   status_payment

I want to make trigger with these conditions 
 - if I insert data in **booking** then the status in **payment** will change automatically into 'unpaid' and **id_booking** in **payment** will insert last **id_booking** in **booking** 
 - if **date_expired** more than 1 hour after **date_booking** the status will update into 'expired' 
 - if **date_expired** is in range 1 hour between **date_booking** the status will update into 'paid'

example :

> **Booking**
>   id_booking : 1
>   id_schedule : 1
>   id_user : 1 
>   date_booking : 2017-01-06 15:44:49 
>   date_expired : null
>
> **Payment**
>   id_payment : 1 
>   id_booking : 1 
>   status_payment : 'unpaid`

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first trigger should be triggered on an insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name`
AFTER INSERT ON `booking` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO payment (id_booking, status_payment)
VALUES (NEW.id_booking, "unpaid")
```

For the second and third trigger you need to use the mysql event shedular, see:
[MySQL trigger: Update when reaching a certain datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923410/mysql-trigger-update-when-reaching-a-certain-datetime) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html